# Cannot Parse Every Line of .Txt File produced with Linux

Tags: vb.net, text-parsing

I have a text file that is over 100000 lines long. When I try to go through all the lines of the file using the following code

```
 Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(txtName)
```

and I count the lines I only see that I read 90000 lines of the file.

I should note that I did get this file off of a Linux machine. If that helps at all
edit: more complete code

```
For Each txtName As String In Directory.EnumerateFiles(mydocpath, "*.log")
    Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(txtName)
         MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
            MyReader.SetDelimiters(" ")
            Dim currentRow As String()
            While Not MyReader.EndOfData
                currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                Console.WriteLine(currentRow.Length)
                LineCount +=1
            End While
    End Using
Next
```

I should mention that is always misses the same line and when I move those lines to another file it can read them just fine, however when I view all special characters in Notepad ++ I cannot find anything out of the ordinary with the line it cannot read or the lines above them

Comment: If your question is about a problem reading a text file, you should show the code you use to read the textfile.

Comment: I think you need to expand a little on the "stuff happens" part.

Comment: Where does the text file come from? If it had come from a Unix or Linux machine, it may have other issues, such as differing line endings.

Comment: @Jon Limjap all I know is that it was transferred from a unix machine, probably unbuntu without using a samba share. I can open and read the file without problems. and I can copy Lines I know I am not reading to other files and read them successfully

Comment: Nothing appears to be wrong in your code.  What method are you using to determine how many lines are in the file?

Comment: @tinstaafl I opened the files up in Notepad ++ and got the line count there

Comment: I would suspect that Notepad++ may not have parsed the line breaks the same as .net does.  Do a visual inspection of the lines and see if some of them don't follow the pattern you'd expect.

Comment: Are you just wanting a line count? Ive done this it can count lines with data and lines even without data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are asking, but it seems you want to get a count of lines in the file if I am correct...

```
Public Class Form1

 Private strFile As String = "LOCATION OF FILE"


Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim wFile As StreamReader
    wFile = New StreamReader(strFile, FileMode.Open)
    Dim count As Integer = 0 'Counter for rows that have something in it
    Dim totalLines As Integer = 0 'Counter for the total lines in the file
    Dim blankLines As Integer = 0 'Counter for the empty lines (optional)

    While (wFile.Peek <> -1)
        If wFile.ReadLine() = String.Empty Then
            blankLines += 1 ' Add to blank line count
        Else
            count += 1 'Add to actual count data from a line
        End If
        totalLines += 1 'The actual total of lines
    End While

    wFile.Close()
 End Sub
End Class
```

Here's a screenshot of my results from a text file I read...

[image: Results from my run...]

On another note, when this file is loaded in Notepad++ I get the same results...

Comment: yeah this thred is more about getting the line counts to match up an how they do not, thank you for submitting this solution though

Comment: I found your issue, the solution provided works quite well... I am actually working on a fix that you posted, but you want a line count that works I gave that to you...

Comment: this worked perfectly, although I still have no idea how my code was skipping lines